# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot infer schema-types from empty result, please use loadDataFrame(schema: (String,String)*)

Tags: neo4j, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to create a dataset using spark neo4j connector

```
Ex: Dataset< Row > myDF= Neo4j.apply(sparkSession.sparkContext()).cypher(myquery, parameters).loadDataFrame(); 
myDF.createOrReplaceTempView("Mytable");
```

This works fine when we have query results from Neo4j.

Here, neo4j query may return 0 records and in that case, I get error as below:

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot infer schema-types from empty result, please use loadDataFrame(schema: (String,String)*)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot infer schema-types from empty result, please use loadDataFrame(schema: (String,String)*)
at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j.loadDataFrame(Neo4j.scala:346)
```

I'd like to handle the No result scenario. 
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In case you or someone else is still having this problem, here how I solved it

```
var df = Neo4j.apply(sparkSession.sparkContext()).cypher("Match (n)-[r]-(m) return n.name as src, m.name as dst").loadDataFrame(schema = ("src","String"),("dst","String"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could solve it by having a RDD is empty check as the result was coming empty sometimes

Answer (score 0):

This also works :

```
 Neo4j myDF1= Neo4j.apply(sparkSession.sparkContext()).cypher(myquery, parameters);
        RDD<Row> rdd = myDF1.loadRowRdd();
         //System.out.println(rdd.isEmpty());
        if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
            Dataset<Row> myDF= rdd.loadDataFrame();
myDF.createOrReplaceTempView("Mytable");
}
```